# How should I send a variable's value from the clients browser to the node.js server?

Tags: node.js

How should I send a variable's value from the clients browser to the node.js server?

localhost:8080/myfile.html

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
if (err) {
res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
return;
}

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end(data);

});

}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
let websocketserver = require("websocket").server; // include "websocket" module
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
if (err) {
res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
return;
} // old code

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.end(data);

});

}).listen(8080); // old code
let wsServer = new websocketserver({ // create instance of WebSocketServer from http server
 httpServer:server,
 autoAcceptConnections: false
})
wsServer.on("request", (req) => { // what happens on request(connection)
 let connection = req.accept("" /* protocol */, req.origin);
 connection.on('message', (msg) => {
     console.log(msg.utf8Data); // output message data to console
 });
 connection.send(/* something here */); // send some message
});
client.html, or something like this
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <!-- some basic code here -->
 <script>
 let socket = new WebSocket('ws://ip-of-server.something:port/');
 socket.onopen = function() { console.log("Oh yeah, i connected~!"); 
 } // set function to execute when socket will open
 socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
   console.log(msg.data); // output message data received from server
 }
 socket.onclose = () => { console.log("Server closed"); };
 </script>
 </html>
```